# how to get parameters of Linux module when it is compiled NOT as a module

Tags: linux, tcp

when a part of Linux Kernel is compiled as a module on could read available parameters with `modinfo` and set them when loading with `modprobe`.

Is it possible to get the values of paramters of something that is configured as part of the kernel?

In particular TCP Cubic is not a module on Ubuntu. Cubic contains a parameter `hystart` to enable and disable hybrid slow start and two more parameters that affect its behavior. Can I somehow read the values of these parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the module parameters in `/sys/module/tcp_cubic/parameters` no matter whether tcp_cubic is built as a module or into the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of sysctl ?
try `sysctl -a | grep tcp`

Comment: yes, the only two cubic parameter there are that cubic is available and that cubic is used by default. as far as I understand these parameters control general tcp code and not particular congestion contorl algorithm

Comment: The kernel tunables are accessible via sysctl as Nikolaidis mentioned; and in some cases, changing values in /sys or /proc (temporary).  To change the behavior of one of the congestion control algo's, you would need to recompile the kernel.

Comment: according to another answer the second part of your statement seems to be not true, the parameters in `/sys/module/tcp_cubic/parameters` are writable

Comment: -1, this answer is incorrect. The `sysctl` only controls stuff under `/proc/sys` and that does not include module parameters (even though some modules may add some additional parameters under `/proc/sys`).